# Results does not show up after search, why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am using the newest Select2 4.0.6-rc.1 and I am making an AJAX search, I am getting results back but for some reason they don't show up as an option on the SELECT element. Maybe I am missing some basic setup but I have been reading the docs and I can't find anything helpful. Here is what I have:

```
<select class="form-control" id="query"></select>

$(function() {
    var $query = $("#query");

    $query.select2({
        width: 550,
        placeholder: 'Search for a form ...',
        minimumInputLength: 3,
        ajax: {
            url: '/ajax/forms/ajax_search_by_name',
            data: function (params) {
                return {
                    q: params.term
                };
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            delay: 250,
            processResults: function (data) {
                return {
                    results: data.items
                };
            }
        }
    });
});
```

The result from the backend looks like:

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1247,
      "name": "amerita_infusion_services_colorado_synagis_referral_form"
    },
    {
      "id": 3471,
      "name": "medicaid_colorado_viekira"
    }
  ]
}
```

Which I think is the right way to return them. I have setup a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/reynierpm/g9c4Le6t/6/) - which BTW I couldn't make it to work with the `/echo/json` request - so you can play with it a little bit.

What I am missing here?

Comment: https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax#transforming-response-data

Comment: @RolandStarke that is not working for me either so I must be doing something else wrong

Comment: mh, i did get the /echo/json to work: https://jsfiddle.net/sdtb6hy6/ sadly i could not solve the real problem.

Comment: ah okay. got your problem. select2 expects `text` and not `name`

Comment: As I said a dummy issue, thx